# Video is not playing in EXPO(iOS)

Tags: javascript, react-native, video, expo

When I put other video URL is working but not for this URL. So the problem with my video URL?

```
<Video
              ref={video}
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
              }}
              source={{
                uri:
                  "http://ec2-3-13-247-85.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/image?id=c8d872b1-510f-43d3-a0ea-8005e85afc3f.mp4",
              }}
              useNativeControls
              resizeMode='contain'
              isLooping
              onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => setStatus(() => status)}
          />
```

Comment: Probably because you're using query in video path (the `?id=`). `react-native-video` haven't support this type of url yet

Comment: Ya, it's working. Thank You 